# Unable to get Without NULL Columns in sqlserver for certain columns

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, null

I am working in sqlserver 2008

```
Security Id Accrued Into Default    Accrued Out of Default  Amort Into Default  Amort Out of Default    Security Code           Geneva Investment Code  Has Position    
WERE000015  NULL                        NULL                     NULL           NULL                    mysec1                   02635PTP8             0        
WERE000016  NULL                        NULL                     NULL           NULL                    mysec2                   00104BAF7             0        
WERE000017  11/11/2011                  NULL                     NULL           NULL                    mysec3                   AU0000ABOHG2          0
```

I am having a table like this. Now I have put these values in Temp table. Now i have to select only those values where NULL is not present in 2,3,4,5 the column

so I applied the MSsql as

```
select * from #temp1 where [Accrued Into Default] IS NOT NULL AND 
 [Accrued Out of Default] IS NOT NULL AND 
 [Amort Into Default] IS NOT NULL AND 
 [Amort Out of Default] IS NOT NULL
```

Now the output I am getting is **Nothing** in any row or column
I think i should get the 3rd row as it contains **Accrued Into Default**

Can anyone tell me why is this happening.

Comment: Change the `AND` with `OR`

Comment: Of course you would get **noting** because you do not have a single row where all 4 columns are not null

Answer (score 2):

Your query is filter for rows where **all** of the fields are `NULL`.

Change your `AND`s to `OR`s and you will get your desired result.

Answer (score 0):

if you want third row then your query should be like this:

```
select * from #temp1 where [Accrued Into Default] IS NOT NULL OR
 [Accrued Out of Default] IS NOT NULL OR
 [Amort Into Default] IS NOT NULL OR
 [Amort Out of Default] IS NOT NULL
```